# How should I display this information if not in a tooltip?

Tags: hover, information, tooltips

I've got a tooltip (image below) that when the user hovers over it, they are given a quick one line summary of what they hovered over and then 8 more lines of information. I already know that's way too much information, but I'm running into a couple issues.

1. There isn't really a way to shorten the information in the `More text` areas.
2. The information needs to be given to the user when they hover over it

   - It's all relevant to how the user might filter the data

To give some more background on the `More text` portion, they will be metrics of the object the user hovers over (Things like `Name`, `Location`, etc.). Those are the pieces of text I'd like to move.

This is the tooltip as it currently stands:

[image: Tooltip]

---

### Question

What would be the best way to show all of the `More text` pieces? I've considered doing something similar to what [this Leaflet map has done for the US States information](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html), but I'm not sure if that is the best method

Comment: It sounds like what you want is some form of [progressive disclosure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_disclosure). Is that it?

Comment: Similar, yes, but the user can filter prior to hovering over the object. This would be extra information to help them determine how they might want to filter the data next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as a good solution. The result will depend a lot on visual and micro-copy you'll use. Maybe combination with an icon indicating there's some more information hidden would be nice to discover the hidden content if it fits the rest of your UI. Or a tutorial that tells the user about it when working with the UI for the first time.

Just keep in mind that this kind of interaction is not ideal for mobile devices in case you need it working on these devices too.